# Why is Hibernate using sequences

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have parent and child entities with IDs that are generated using the strategy `GenerationType.TABLE` because I'm working with a MySQL database.

If I create the parent without specifying an ID (i.e., create the parent for the first time), add new children to it, and save the parent, then hibernate works as expected and uses the MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT column feature.

However, If I create a parent and specify an ID (i.e., instantiating a parent that has already been persisted), add a child to it, and save the child, then hibernate issues a `select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences ...` and uses that as the child's PK.

Likewise, if I instantiate a parent by getting it from the database via `session.get(Parent, 1)`, add a new child to it, and save either the parent or the child, then hibernate uses sequences to get the child's PK.

If I create enough new parents  (32767, to be exact) to run up the mysql AUTO_INCREMENT counter, there would be failures due to the primary key not being unique enough.

Here are my parent and child entities (named Location and Category, respectively):

```
@Entity(name="location")
public class Location {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE) @Column(name="location_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="location")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<Category> categories;

    ...
}

@Entity(name="category")
public class Category {
    @ID @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE) @Column(name="category_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="location_id")
    private Location location;
}
```

Here is the hibernate code:

```
Hibernate: select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'category' for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'category'
Hibernate: insert into category (location_id, category_id) values (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beforehand: I have no answer why hibernate uses another strategy when persisting your child record. But I may give you some answers or hints about the other issues you described:

Regarding the strategy `GenerationType.TABLE`, your application relies on the database functionality of generating an ID. This may cause database round-trips for each new database record inserted. When using an alternative strategy like hi-lo, the generator will reserve a bunch of ids (for example 100 or 1000) by contacting the database only once. This may improve performance greatly. On the other side, you may loose some ID when the application is restarted. If you may life with this issue hi-lo should be considered.

Another benefit of using a strategy not relying on a database product is, that if you switch databases you may keep your mappings.